# What was the Sperry "Follow Up and Comp. Mech. (Type K9)"

Tags: military, aviation-history, avionics

I found online a "Computing Gun-sight" used in WWII B-24 and B-26 bombers:

[image]

[Source](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/sperry-k9-turret-sight-computer-b24-1936176881)

Sperry Gyroscope Co., Brooklyn, NY, part # 655432:

[image]

[Source](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/sperry-k9-turret-sight-computer-b24-1936176881)

I have looked through the Sperry Corp. Archives site to no avail. I think I own a rare relic of military aviation technology and I would appreciate any help to determine its value, as well as any information source to learn more about it.

I have several pictures available to send if that would help with identification.

Comment: I dont' have a good answer, but to start with this computer is associated with a sight. It controls a moving mirror stabilized by a gyroscope, and helps the gun operator to keep the target centered, and possibly to predict the deflection required to compensate for target relative velocity. See [gyro-gunsight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_gunsight). Similar devices: [K3/K4](https://www.glennsmuseum.com/items/k3_k4_gunsights/). [K4 details](https://aeroantique.com/products/ball-turret-gun-sight-k-4-sperry-b-17-b-24?variant=35859115338).